# Is it possible to use r markdown with r.net

Tags: r, vb.net, r-markdown, r.net

I am working on a form in vb.net that also needs to produce reports (basically a couple of tables and charts). I was going to create the reports directly through vb.net but recently discovered R.net which lets you use R from .Net. Seeing as there is more support for creating reports in RMarkdown, I was thinking of using R.net to pass the data into R and then hav RMarkdown generate the report pdfs.

So, I wanted to see if it was possible to use RMarkdown with r.net, so far to me it seems like you can only run operations from the regular command line.

Thanks for the help,

Comment: `rmarkdown` is a package (whose name you are misspelling). Aren't you able to load and run code with R packages?

Comment: Yes, I just did not know how to knit from the console. I had only done it from the R Markdown window. Richie showed me how to do that below. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your report template in markdown (or whatever markup language you prefer), then pass a call to `knitr::knit` to R.